# Web Api Rest method receives JObject wrapped in another JObject as a key value

Tags: json, rest, post, asp.net-web-api, sencha-touch

I have problem with json which is sent from the sencha touch client to the rest web abi web service.

When i send POST request from Sencha it looks like:

```
var paramsData = Ext.encode({
            FormId: '5',
            WorkcardId: 'a1234',
            FormDataSet: 'dataset'
        });
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: JsonTestClient.app.webserviceUrl',
            scope: this,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jsonToken.access_token },
            params: paramsData,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response, options) {
                //
            },
            failure: function (response, options) {
                //
            }
        });
```

and paramsData value is : "{"FormId":"5","WorkcardId":"a1234","FormDataSet":"dataset"}"

However on WebApi RestService in the method

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string SaveForm([FromBody] JObject jsonData)
        {
            //
        }
```

jsonData looks like

```
{
  "{\"FormId\":\"5\",\"WorkcardId\":\"a1234\",\"FormDataSet\":\"dataset\"}": ""
}
```

So it seems like my initial json is wrapped in another object and is used as a key value.

Any ideas what can be wrong? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kasharma, i payed attention to how looks FormData in the sencha touch request.

From that i found a solution. I had to add
jsonData: paramsData,
to the post request

Answer (score 0):

From client site(sencha),Can you verify JSON in the http request body?

From server side,did you write all the contract for that method like what kind of parameter it can accept?

```
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
```

Above property should be placed inside the interface(or directly inside class if you did not have interface) that defines the contract regarding the input parameter.

Comment: thanks for your response.

FormData:
{"FormId":"5","WorkcardId":"a1234","FormDataSet":"dataset"}:

I just now payed attention to that ":" in the end of the json string. Probably that explains why i get json on the server in such format.  But then what am i doing wrong on the sencha side?

(regarding all that stuff that defines contract parameters, you dont do it in new Web Api)